# How to know that the loop was breaked early?

Tags: c++, c++11, c99, c++14

```
for(int i=0; i<len_arr; i++)
    if(arr[i] == some_num){
        printf("The idx of %d is: %d\n", some_num, i);
        break;
    }
if(i == len_arr)
    printf("Number not found.\n");
```

This doesn't work. Because that `i` can't be accessed outside the loop.

I have thought of two ways to achieve what effect I want.

But my question is, **is there any other more elegant way** to do the effect?

Way 1:

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<len_arr; i++)
    if(arr[i] == some_num){
        printf("The idx of %d is: %d\n", some_num, i);
        break;
    }
if(i == len_arr)
    printf("Number not found.\n");
```

Way 2:

```
for(int i=0; (i<len_arr) && (printf("Number not found.\n")); i++)
    if(arr[i] == some_num){
        printf("The idx of %d is: %d\n", some_num, i);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I would vote Way1. Or add a boolean flag, which isn't that elegant but states clearly what you want to do.

Comment: Are you sure your second way works?

Comment: First question..why don't you create your own scope of " for loop". just put brackets. Am I missing something?

Comment: Way 2 looks elegant to me.

Comment: @UzumakiIchigo It's elegant as long as you want `Number not found.` printed every iteration of the loop. The condition needs to be `||`, not `&&`; it's easy to make such mistakes when trying to write *clever* code like that. @Jennya C or C++? Obviously the two languages will have different idiomatic methods to find an element in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find Luka Rahne's solution the most ideomatic.

If you really want to do the loop you could do it like this:

```
for(size_t i(0); i <= len_arr; ++i)
{
    if(i == len_arr)
    {
        std::cout << "Number not found." << std::endl;
    }
    else if(arr[i] == some_num)
    {
        std::cout << "Found " << some_num << " at index: " << i << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you cant express this easily, dont use loop at all. You can use dedicated function for searching in this concrete case.

```
auto start = arr;
auto end = arr + len;
auto val = std::find(start,end,some_num);
if (val != end)
   printf("The idx of %d is: %d\n", some_num, std::distance(start,val));
else
   printf("Number not found.\n");
```

Comment: That *is* the most elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this goal. I used to do like this:

```
bool found = false;
for(int i=0; i<len_arr; i++)
{
    if(arr[i] == some_num)
    {
        printf("The idx of %d is: %d\n", some_num, i);
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!found)
    printf("Number not found.\n");
```

This variation looks the most clear/readable to me.

Comment: Even with Luka Rahne's solution ?

Comment: Well, the question was "How to know that the loop was breaked early?". I supposed the code was just an example to demonstrate an idea and not a "production code". If the question is "how to write properly the given code?", then Luka Rahne's solution will be the way to go.

Comment: @SergiiKhaperskov You're right. The code is a demonstration. In my real situation I am not finding something.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use std like Luka suggests and only want to do a simple loop, you can do as I always do:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < len_arr && arr[i] != some_num; i++);
if(i < len_arr)
    printf("The idx of %d is: %d\n", some_num, i);
else
    printf("Number not found.\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally i don't like a break in a loop and this is my solution:

```
bool found = false;
for(int i=0; i<len_arr && !found; i++){
    if(arr[i] == some_num){
        printf("The idx of %d is: %d\n", some_num, i);
        found = true;
    }
}
if(!found)
    printf("Number not found.\n");
```